# Understanding line of given proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have to understand a set of proofs and I don't understand the reasoning behind this line

"This is an injection, if $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$ then $F_{b_1}$ And $F_{b_2}$ intersect, which we shown never happens." In the proof below.

May someone explain what the terms $F_{b_1}$ And $F_{b_2}$ refer to? And why this sentence is true?

Proposition. If $f : A \to B$ is a surjection, there is an injection $g : B \to A$, so that $f \circ g = \textrm{id}_B$ .

Proof:
For any $b \in B$, define the set $F_b$ = $\{ x \in A\mid f(x) = b \} $,so that $F_b \subseteq A$. This set is never empty since $f : A \to B$ is assumed to be surjective. If $b \ne b′$ then $F_b$ and $F_{b′}$ are disjoint. Indeed, if $a \in F_b \cap F_{b′}$ then, by definition, $f(a) = b$ and $f(a) = b′$, which is impossible as $b \ne  b′$. Now define a function, $g:B\to A$ so that $g(b)$ is chosen from $F_b$ i.e. $g(b) \in F_b$. This is an injection, if $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$ then $F_{b_1}$ and $F_{b_2}$ intersect, which we shown never happens. Finally, $f(g(b)) = b$, because $g(b) \in F_b$ and $f$ applied to any element of $F_b$ results in $b$. Hence $f \circ g = \textrm{id}_B$ .

Comment: I believe $F_{b_1} = \{x \in A | f(x) = b_1\}$ for some $b_1 \in B$. Likewise with $F_{b_2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F_{b_1}=\{x\in A : f(x)=b_1\}$ and similarly with $F_{b_2}$ as was mentioned in the comment.

As for why the sentence is true, I hope the following will help:

Since $g(b)$ is chosen from $F_b$, if $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$, then $g(b_1)\in F_{b_1}$, and $g(b_1)=g(b_2)\in F_{b_2}$, then $g(b_1)\in F_{b_2}\cap F_{b_2}$. But as this is impossible if $b_1\ne b_2$ as shown in the prior two sentences of the proof. Therefore we have if $b_1\ne b_2$, then $g(b_1)\ne g(b_2)$ so $g$ is injective.

Comment: Both your comment and @Gregory Grant 's comment were helpful. Why is it better to use the word "IF $b \neq b'$ . . . " instead of "LET $b \neq b'$ . . ."?

Comment: @Forever_A_Student Honestly there isn't much difference, "if" is just perhaps the way I'd prefer to state it, since there is an implied "let $b,b'\in A$" prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

$F_{b_1}$ are exactly the points which map to $b_1$ and $F_{b_2}$ are exactly the points that map to $b_2$.  So the fact that they have empty intersection is really not very deep it just says one number cannot map to two different places.